# Can JSON Format support Scene graph?

Tags: json, three.js

I am attempting to write a STEP loader that converts STEP to the THREE JS JSON format.
However, I have not seen anything in the JSON format information about creating a scene graph - i.e. a hierarchical scene structure.
Is it possible to do so?
Thanks - Imtiaz

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a Loader, you don't need Three.js JSON format as an intermediate step. As the other loaders do, just create the THREE.Geometry, THREE.Mesh, THREE.Object3D etc objects directly as you go about parsing the STEP file. Object3D is the basic container which you can use to create hierarchies. In addition to being able to contain meshes, you can `.add()` any number of other Object3Ds into Object3D.

If you still want to have this JSON step, the three JSON model format itself does not have support for hierarchies. But there is also (rather new I believe) Three.js object JSON format, which can store hierarchies. See THREE.ObjectLoader , it is in src/loaders/ObjectLoader.js

Comment: The STEP conversion cannot happen in the browser as I am using Python and OpenCascade.
However, I will look into the OBJECT JSON format.